# Cannot create the JSON response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to test a Module and I need to recreate a `json` as follows:

`$billing_info['billing']['source']->exp_year`

I tried to recreate it as follows:

```
$arr = json_encode(['exp_month' => 07, 'funding' => 'credit', 'brand' => 'Visa', 'last4' => '4242']);

$billing_info =  [ 'billing' => [ 'source' => $arr ]  ];
```

But I'm not able to call `dd($billing_info['billing']['source']->exp_year);`

Comment: if the array is already json encoded you wont be able to access the vars like that..

Comment: @Daniel: How else can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode your json string before you can access object variables again:

```
dd(json_decode($billing_info['billing']['source'])->exp_month);
```

If you really need to create an object as described, you can do the following:

```
$arr = json_encode(['exp_month' => 07, 'funding' => 'credit', 'brand' => 'Visa', 'last4' => '4242']);
$billing_info =  [ 'billing' => [ 'source' => json_decode($arr) ]  ];
```

And than you can call your

```
dd($billing_info['billing']['source']->exp_month);
```

method. In the example you described, there is no need to encode/decode to json anyway, but I assume you receive your json string from somewhere else.

Comment: I just have to recreate the `$billing_info` to be called like `$billing_info['billing']['source'])->exp_year`. So, how can I fake the data in it?

Comment: What if I need to have `$billing_info['billing']->customer_id`  along with it?

Comment: So I can access `$billing_info['billing']['source']->id`  and  `$billing_info['billing']->customer_id`

Comment: You never mentioned something like `customer_id`. where should this data come from?

Comment: I added it after you answered. How can I access something like this?

Comment: You added it where? I have no information about the data you are talking so I can not give you an advice

Comment: I mean what you answered is correct. Also later when I checked the data at my part again, I saw I need to access data like $billing_info['billing']->customer_id. So in the 'billing' array, there's a key value pair also. Like {customer_id : 12}

Comment: So the data would be $billing_info = [billing => {customer_id : 12}, source => [{exp_year : 2018 ....}]]

Comment: An array can not contain properties because it is no type of stdClass. Please ask a new question for this one, I would be interrested if this is possible by some sort of hack.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` creates a string, not an object, so you can't access properties of it. You have to call `json_decode` first:

```
dd(json_decode($billing_info['billing']['source'])->exp_year);
```

See also [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) docs.

You can also cast the array to object, like that:

```
$arr = (object) array('exp_month' => 07, 'funding' => 'credit', 'brand' => 'Visa', 'last4' => '4242');
```

You can then access its properties like that:

```
var_dump($arr->exp_month);
```

Comment: I just have to recreate the `$billing_info` to be called like `$billing_info['billing']['source'])->exp_year`. So, how can I fake the data in it?